# nested mysql query with double select statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple problem regarding a nested query.
To be honest I don't know if it can be done through one query only or if I'll have to use PHP.

Put simply, I want to return the users information from the users tables by the users IDs returned from a select statement in relations table.

I can do this by 2 queries and some PHP loop but for saving resources, but I think it's better to combine it into 1 query and single loop.

First query

```
SELECT UserID FROM relations WHERE GroupID = '1'
```

Second query I need to retrieve the user info from the user table by the returned UsersIDs from the first select statement.

I can do this by loop through the ID and making the queries but I think I can get all in 1 query.

Thanks

Comment: You should use MYSQL JOINS for your requirement. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the typical way to do that:

```
SELECT     users.*
FROM       users
INNER JOIN relations
ON         users.id = relations.userid
WHERE      relations.groupid = 1
```

I noticed you were using quotes around the 1 in your query. I am assuming group id is an integer value, in which case you should not use quotes.

The answers that use an IN subquery are likely to be less performant. Esp. with MySQL, the JOIN should always we the preferred way to combine results from tables, since MySQL has particularly lackluster subquery implementation.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select * from user_table where id in(SELECT UserID FROM relations WHERE GroupID = '1')
                                   OR
Select * from user_table u INNER JOIN relations r ON u.UserID=r.UserID WHERE r.GroupID='1'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from user_typw 
where userID in (SELECT UserID FROM relations WHERE GroupID = '1')
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select * from user where UserID  in
(SELECT UserID FROM relations WHERE GroupID = '1')
```

or

```
select * from user U where exists 
(SELECT * FROM relations R WHERE U.UserID=R.UserID and  R.GroupID = '1')
```

or

```
select U.*
from user U join relations R 
on U.UserID=R.UserID 
where  R.GroupID = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM user_table ut LEFT JOIN relations r on ut.UserID=r.UserID where r.GroupID=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT A.field1,B.field2 FROM table1 A LEFT JOIN table2 B ON A.common_ID=B.common_ID WHERE field = 'abc'